# Google App Engine Memcache - Preferred Structure [Java]

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have to write the application for Car Manufacture Industries details in Google App Engine [Java]

It is like having the hierarchy structures like below.

Manufacture  - Body Types - Car model - Interior component(Engine/Fuel type/...) and each has comments and file attachments

If want to get details multiple manufacture then it is taking long time in DB sine it has to run nearly 8 query from HRD (for single manufacture)
I just want to know best approach to store in the memcache - for example - If I save each and every object in the memcache then I have to manage the keys of each items in the separate keys. And If want to save all the result in the one key - like json or xml or List then for each item i have to manage them separately on update of the item as well as update in the json,xml or List and that need to be split them if it is more than 10KB since we use dedicated memcache.

What will be the best approach to manage this kind of operations?

Is there any other solution, please let me know.

thanks

Krishnan

Comment: if you use NDB then some types of operation are automatically cached.

Comment: Thanks, Is NDB available in JAVA App Engine? I preferred in Java GAE

Comment: I don't know. I've re-tagged your question.

Comment: memcache is only going to help if you are requesting the same object multiple times and frequently.  It needs to be considered only as a cache, and can be expunged at any time.  In python it is either done on a per key basis (under the hood with ndb) or you cache the result of an expensive datastore operation which you expect to frequently.  If you are not repeating the same read operation frequently you may find memcache adds an overhead with little benefit.  How in java will depend on what api you use. Cache invalidation can be an issue if you cache multiple entities with a single key

Comment: memcache entities can be up to 1MB.

Comment: Yes, Entity can be max up to 1MB, I have lot of doubts, how we will be able to manage all this as objects as each object or like collective result which will be the better or best approach? Thanks. Basically this has object with more properties, I just want to design the basic structure, it is taking delay too much and I don't want the call should not take more than 5 sec max. So I want to apply the logic in terms of read and writing the object should be faster.

Comment: @KrishnanTringer, no NDB is not available on Java App Engine runtime. But you can use a library like [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify) that will provide this functionality among other things (I strongly encourage you to use such a library). JPA may also provide this.

Comment: Thanks, I have to use Third Party Library Only. Do we have any other approach?